# 2 BroadcastReceivers and 1 static variable

Tags: android

I have 2 BroadcastReceivers in my android application. They are in the same package.
If in the onReceive() method, they both read/write a static class variable (in a separate Util class).  Does android create 1 copy of that static class variable or 2 (1 for each receiver)?

And what do I need to do to make sure they are accessing the static class variable not corrupting the data?

Comment: You should rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will only be **one instance** of the static variable.  From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html:

> A class variable is any field declared
>   with the static modifier; this tells
>   the compiler that there is exactly one
>   copy of this variable in existence,
>   regardless of how many times the class
>   has been instantiated.

To avoid problems, you will have to make sure the static variable is thread safe.  Some data structures, like `Vector`,  are already thread safe, so you would not have to do anything further.  Otherwise, you may have to use the [synchronized](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) keyword or something from the [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static variables, make the class Singleton.

"And what do I need to do to make sure they are accessing the static class variable not corrupting the data?" -  add `synchronized` to getters/setters

Comment: But in order to make Singleton, i still have a static class variable called 'theInstance()' so what does that help me?